# Android studio passing data between 2 fragments! Getting an error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments, which are being replaced in a container inside the main activity layout. One fragment passes the data through an interface whenever clicking on the button. When I click the button, I want my first fragment to be replaced with the second fragment, in the same container. However, I have an issue...

In the second fragment, I need to get the data and use it on a view. Now, in the second fragment, I have a method for getting the data. In the activity, I know that I need to find the ID of the second fragment in order to use its method. However, this fragment doesn't  have any ID (because I'm going through fragments by code). Since I can't find the ID of the fragment, I'm getting an error and I can't pass the data to the second fragment.

How to solve this? Can it be solved?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you give some sample code and examples? This question is very hard to follow.

Comment: Hey graham ill post here html links for the fragment and the activity.
this one is the fragment1:file:///C:/Users/eran/Desktop/new%202.html , and this one is the activity : file:///C:/Users/eran/Desktop/new%201.html

Comment: Eran we cannot access your computer to see the files ;) Does my answer not resolve your issue? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the fragment by ID if you have it in XML layout.

If you are handling your fragment in code, you can use a TAG and find it by that.

Starting a fragment

```
String FRAGMENT_TAG = "myFragment";
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new MyFragment(), FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
```

Getting the fragment by TAG

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
if (fragment != null) {
    fragment.passData(data);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a static constant for fragment argument and then call newInstance from second fragment to initialize first fragment and passing data from 1 to 2

Below code is example of above description:

```
private static final String ARG_DATE = "date";

   public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(Date date) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_DATE, date);

        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

to retrieve/resolve DatePickerFragment argument data:

```
Date date = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);
```

to initialize Fragment in another xxxFragment(that's mean pass the crime's date data from xxFragment to DatePickerFragment):

```
DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mCrime.getDate());
```

you can check out my github repository to understand %100

```
[https://github.com/Zfr21/CriminalIntent/commit/2ed69c056988818f6f6423762c97a6bf1a82b547][1]
```